# Accessing model method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I could be wrong about my MVC logic, but what I'm trying to do is take user input from a view and pass that information to the database. But before doing so, I'd like to determine the type of data that was submitted by analyzing some regex (and then passing the type to the database as well as the content).

But for some reason I'm getting an error (undefined method `get_type') that the method I'm calling from the model doesn't exist. Am I wrong in thinking that this method should be in the model?

**Controller:**

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(
      content: params[:post][:content]
      type: get_type(params[:post][:content])
    )
    @post.save
  end
```

**Model:**

```
  def get_type
    if self.content =~ /(\.jpg|\.png|\.bmp|\.gif)$/
      return 'image'
    end
  end
```

Giant disclaimer: I just started ruby (and rails for that matter) a few days ago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call the model :

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(
      content: params[:post][:content]
      type: Post.get_type(params[:post][:content])
    )
    @post.save
  end
```

And add the 'self' keyword:

```
  def self.get_type(content)
    if content =~ /(\.jpg|\.png|\.bmp|\.gif)$/
      return 'image'
    end
  end
```

But I think **you should set the type in a `before_create` statement**:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  before_create :set_type
  #...

  def set_type
    if self.content =~ /(\.jpg|\.png|\.bmp|\.gif)$/
      self.type = 'image'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ah, wonderful! would you mind just telling me what the before_create will do?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html To make it short, the `before_create` allows you to trigger the specified method (here `set_type`) before the object is created (saved in the DB, create a new entry). There is several callbacks, like `before_save`, `after_validation`, etc. You can hook into the life cycle of an Active Record object

Comment: Oh and also a useful link to get the guidelines for Rails: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide

Comment: So if I used before_create, would I not have to call the method in the controller?

Comment: Exactly! The `set_type` method, if used with a before_create, will be called at everytime you create a new Post object (not when you update an existing object: use `before_update` or something like this)

Comment: That's brilliant! Oh, I think I'm starting to like rails.

Comment: You're going to love it soon ;)